# How to remove trace command from Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, trace

I want to remove trace commands while creating the compiled SWF file and while goggling I come to know that Setting Omit Trace Actions to 'true' will fulfill this requirement but when I am using this key value pair in configuration file it is giving compilation error, so what can be the reason and how to resolve this issue.

Kindly note I am using version 3 of Flex.

Comment: mxmlc does not [have this compiler flag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html). I think it's something specific to the compiler used in Flash Pro, which is proprietary to Adobe.

Comment: @@Riaster: What can we do to remove Trace commands from compiled swf

Comment: @RIAstar I wasn't sure which compiler flag you were referring to; you just linked to a page with all of them.

Comment: @Reboog711 Sorry, I meant the one mentioned in the question (omit-trace-actions), which can not be found in the page I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I use a custom `Trace` class:

```
public class Trace {
  public static var shouldTrace:Boolean = true;
  public static function out(message:String):void {
    if (shouldTrace) {
      trace(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Then throughout my application I replace all my `trace()` calls with:

```
Trace.out("trace statement");
```

It's not quite as smooth while developing, but I can turn off all my trace statements by setting `shouldTrace` when I want to compile the release SWF.